# How to locally export config from a remote environment?

Tags: importing-exporting, configuration

If I have config that's out of sync on production, I may want to export it without copying down the database, or I may have environment-specific config that interferes with exporting config from the local environment. Is there a way to export config from a remote environment locally?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Turns out drush has a `config-pull` command to handle exactly this:

https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config/config-pull/

However, it doesn't work with config_ignore as far as I can tell.

The original answer for posterity:

I've found that this bash command does the trick (on Mac OS X):

```
yes n | drush @site.env cim sync --preview=diff | \
sed -E 's/([\-]{3} ).*(\/.*.yml)/\1a\/config\/sync\2/' | \
sed -E 's/([\+]{3} ).*(\/.*.yml)/\1b\/config\/sync\2/' > cim.patch && \
interdiff -q cim.patch /dev/null > cex.patch && \
git apply cex.patch && \
rm cex.patch cim.patch
```

We use the preview argument of drush config-import (passing in 'n' when it prompts to import), clean up path names with sed, [reverse the patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902388) from import to export, and finally apply it and clean up. Note that you have to be on the same git branch as production.

With drush 9, the output and `yes` functionality changes a little, so you can instead use:

```
drush @site.env cim sync --no --preview=diff 2>/dev/null | \
sed -E 's/([\-]{3} ).*(\/.*.yml)/\1a\/config\/sync\2/' | \
sed -E 's/([\+]{3} ).*(\/.*.yml)/\1b\/config\/sync\2/' > cim.patch && \
interdiff -q cim.patch /dev/null > cex.patch && \
git apply cex.patch && \
rm cex.patch cim.patch
```

Comment: `cpull` doesn't export active config, it just rsync's the staged config from the @source directory.